# Having problem in adding action on VF page button

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, java, event

Below is my VF and controller,i am having trouble in adding action on commandbutton on VF page. if i add searchEvent in commantbutton action it will create new class. i want to do like that when someone click on that submit button, at that time searchEvent function should be executed.

Other problem i am having is how can i store json response from eventbrite API? i want to search event name in eventbrite from my visualforce page.

VF PAGE

```
<apex:page controller="ESFormController">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Event Search Form">
       <apex:pageBlockButtons >
               <apex:commandButton action="{!}" value="Submit" id="submitButton" reRender="searchEvent" />
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>  
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Event" columns="1"> 
             <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >                    
                    Event Name <font color="red">*</font> 
                    <apex:inputText value="{!query}" id="searchEvent"> 
 <table width="99%">    
     <tr>      
     <td width="33%"><apex:outputText >{!querys}</apex:outputText></td>      
     </tr>    
    </table>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class ESFormController
{
    public String querys { get; set; }
    public String query { get; set; }

    public ESFormController(){
    query = 'this';


    }


    public void searchEvent(string query)
    {


    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?location.address=' + query);
    req.setMethod('GET');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer #############');

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    System.debug(res.getBody());
    querys = res.getBody();    

    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass your input text value to your searchevent method. It's value will be available inside your controller so your controller will be modified as shown below

```
//call this method from the page command button
public void CallAPI()
{
   searchEvent(query);
}


public void searchEvent(String pagequery)
{


Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/?location.address=' + pagequery);
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer #############');

HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
System.debug(res.getBody());
querys = res.getBody();    

}
```

and this will be your commandbutton code

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!CallAPI}" value="Submit" id="submitButton" reRender="searchEvent" />
```

Comment: I've moved all the comments to chat to keep the post clean - you can carry on the discussion there if need to be :) http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34578/discussion-on-answer-by-himanshu-having-problem-in-adding-action-on-vf-page-butt